# Firefox playing Blurred Youtube videos on Ubuntu 20.10 (ARM64)-Raspberry PI 4(8Gb)

Tags: firefox, video, youtube

I've been using Ubuntu in my Raspberrys since 19.xx and now I'm running 20.10 (arm64).

Since some days ago, I noticed that Firefox 88.x was playing blurred videos on youtube.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKvPO.png)

It looks like a failling Chroma Key or something like.

Some hours later came the Firefox update to 89.0 and the problem remains the same.

This problem does not happen on Chromium or Vivaldi, and VLC plays ok too.

I could think this is a Firefox problem but it started to happen during version 89.x and can be some video module in system. I dont know.

Have someone seen this problem???

Thanks,

Cury

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is Firefox > 88 on Raspberry.

I decided to make a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10 in a spare SD Card.

Without updating anything and Firefox is playing videos OK.

Then I started to update all the system, except Firefox 82.x.

Firefox is playing videos OK.

After updating Firefox to 89 the problem began.

Now I'll try Firefox Forum.

Thanks,

Cury

Comment: You should probably report the bug to Ubuntu/Launchpad first.  It may relate to specific patches applied by Ubuntu: it's good manners to only go to the upstream forum if you installed it from the upstream providers, you are certain it isn't distro-specific, or the distribution maintainer is inactive.

Firefox is a bit of an exception to this rule, due to some trademark politics, but in general you shouldn't go to upstream for problems that might not be their fault.

Comment: Problem solved  upgrading to Firefox 89.0.1